# Want to hide the textbox in a web browser app for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a web browser app for windows phone 7 using web browser control. I just want to hide the textBox(used for **entering URL**) named as **"UrlTextBox"** when the user touches on  the web browser control(named as **"browsers"**) and again if the user **tap** on the web browser control, the textBox should be Visible. Can anyone help me with this??? Thanks in advance for your hard work!!!

Comment: I dont know what to do Robaticus, since am new to these things. Can you help with this or can you tell me via codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely not going to be able to do this the way you want.  The WebBrowser control doesn't pass through the gestures, as it needs them itself, so tapping on the web browser isn't going to do anything.

What you might want to look into is either using the `ApplicationBar` or creating something "like" an `ApplicationBar` that handles the tap event.  That, combined with toggling the textbox's `Visibility` between `Visible` and `Collapsed` should get you what you need.

Comment: But now, on the first click of the button(used for collapsing), the textBox is collaped but from the second click on-wards, it's not getting visible again. Can you tell me what to do with this thing?